# Apex - How to join Arrays?

Tags: apex

How add three arrays in Apex programming ?

```
String[] s1 = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
String[] s2 = new String[]{"d", "e", "f"};
String[] s3 = new String[]{"g", "h", "i"};
```

I need to create the single array in apex?

Comment: Downvote from me for lack of research. This is a really basic question that can be answered by looking through documentation. (Specifically, [the documentation on the List class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm)). Googling for "apex <insert class name here>" usually works pretty well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `public Void addAll(List fromList)` method to merge all elements from one list into another. Refer [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm) for more details.

Below code merges list `s2` and `s3` into `s1`

```
String[] s1 = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
String[] s2 = new String[]{"d", "e", "f"};
String[] s3 = new String[]{"g", "h", "i"};
s1.addAll(s2);
s1.addAll(s3);
```